# Installing Stripe dependencies in Firebase CLI for a Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into my Flutter app.

I have finished the Flutter part of it and now I am trying to use Firebase Cloud functions to manage the server side part of the Stripe payment.

I have installed Firebase CLI on my Mac.

Then I have open the Mac terminal and put the command

```
firebase init
```

Then I have selected the `Functions` option, then I have selected an existing project, then I have selected `JavaScript` for language, then I have selected YES to install the dependencies with npm.

Then I have put `cd functions` to enter into the functions folder.

Inside the functions folder I have put `npm install stripe --save`

but an error is shown:

[image]

I would like to know what am I missing in order to install Stripe dependencies to be use with my Firebase project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to [install Node.js and the npm command line interface](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm).

The previous steps described in your question are the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

[Install node with homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node#default)

```sh
brew install node
```